# paintComponent executed twice and drawing failure

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm doing a little personnal project to improve my java skill.

What I do there, is that i create 3 JPanel (a global one, and 2 into the global).

In one of them (the right one), I want to draw blocks. Those blocks have a random height, width and an unique id.

In one of my java class, i create a random number of blocks. Then, I'm doing a function to draw those blocks and here are the problems. 
First of all, the paintComponent function is executing twice, and I only want it to be executed one time.

Secondly, my blocks are.. not draw very well.. here is a picture of 20 blocks drawing into my panel (to debug, I put a fix number of blocks). My windows is 900x700.

Here is my paintComponent function, I tried to see where I did a mistake, but 
I pull my hair off..

Comment: "my blocks are.. not draw very well" - what would be an expected result? Can you provide an example image of what you'd expect as well as a corresponding image generated by your code where the blocks are distinguishable (e.g. by different coloring)?

Comment: "paintComponent function is executing twice and I only want it to be executed one time" - how often components are updated/redrawn often is left to the ui frameworks so you shouldn't rely on that happening only once. Instead write your code in a way that it doesn't matter whether it is called once or 100s of times - that means separate the model (which probably would contain `listeBlocPlacePanelBloc` etc.) and updates to it from the drawing code (which uses the model).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is what I want it to do [link](https://imgur.com/a/SCNSaPn) I don't really know how to change color of every object.. I started few months back so I'm not really good at it.

Comment: Well, here is my ui [link](https://pastebin.com/fJxU9e41) I don't see why it should happening twice.. The paintComponent is inside my java class `GererPanelBloc` which I call it in `initPanelBloc` And also, my Bloc java class is only this  [link](https://pastebin.com/Wvzc8XGr) .. I'm lost

Comment: Well the UI will repaint a component whenever it deems it necessary. That might happen when you resize the window, move it, just invalidate it programmatically etc. etc. - the main lesson is: don't rely on the number of repaints! That's bound to cause problems and is bad style anyways. Paint methods that have sideeffects (i.e. they do things other than painting (like yours is adding elements to a non-local list) will cause more headaches than they solve.

Comment: so to resolve the paintComponent executing twice, I need to create a local list ? I'm sorry, I'm a bit lost and since I'm on this probleme since hours.. lol

Comment: You need to separate handling the list additions etc. from painting. That is, provide some model for your panel (which could be as simple as a list inside the panel) and add the blocks in some code that is _not_ directly involved in painting. In your paint method you then just iterate over that list but you don't change it. - In your code it seems as if `listeBlocPasEncorePlacePanel` could be that list albeit the name would be misleading. You'd just not remove the blocks from that list but iterate over it _every time_ (and you'd not need `listeBlocPlacePanelBloc` anymore).

Comment: If I understand well, I need to put a List inside a model (in my case, the java class `GererPanelBloc `, and then do a function which put the blocks inside the panel (in my case `paintComponent`) but I need to change it since I paint & add things on my list. Then I iterate my list of blocs, then remove the blocs in the list I put into the panel and I iterate again in this list. Is that right ?

Comment: While painting you should not add or remove anything from that list. If the list changes then invalidate the panel to make the UI repaint it - but that should happen outside the painting code (which comprises `paintXxx` methods and others). That means your painting code _only reads_ from the list - and to prevent visual artifacts or `ConcurrentModificationException`s that could occur when the list changes while painting you might want to use 2 lists: one that you read from and one that's changed and after the changes are done both are swapped (aka "double buffering").

Comment: Ok.. I understand what you mean, but in my case, I don't see how to do that.. It take me like 4 hours to make the paintComponent function so.

Comment: Here is the blocs with some Color [link](https://imgur.com/a/js7hpYn)

Comment: Please add that image to your question and if you add it like `![title][url]` it will be displayed right away. However, we'd also need to know what you'd want it to look like (and while you're at it please format your code nicely). Also, if you're operation on a single list in readonly mode then you'd not need that last if-else block. Just treat all the blocks the same and debug your code to check the offsets (which I assume are wrong).

Comment: First, I added the 2 pictures, and I format the code). Well, I'm lost with all the info you gave me. I'm in front of my initial code, what I need to do in the order : `Remove the "add.(bloc) from paintComponent` `Have only 1 List` `Remove the last if-else` `debug` But of course I need to change things in the function, to replace for example the `if-else` I need to remove..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target picture indicates you basically want to render the images in lines, i.e. if an image wouldn't fit into the current line you'd start a new one. Thus you need to track the offsets for x and y as well as the hight of the highest block in the line. This means for each block you'd do something like this (untested but a little debugging should help if this isn't 100% correct):

```
//maximum width of a line
int maxWidth = 300;

//Space in pixels between the border as well as the blocks
int paddingX = 5;
int paddingY = 5;

//the offset for the next block
int offsetX = paddingX;
int offsetY = paddingY;

int currentLargestHeight = 0;

for( Block block : blocks ) {
  //if the block doesn't fit into the "line" start a new one
  //we assume an empty line always can take at least one block
  if( block.getWidth() > (maxWidth - offsetX - paddingX) ) {
    //advance down
    offsetY += currentLargestHeight + paddingY;

    //we have a new line so the current largest height is 0 again
    currentLargestHeight = 0;

    //start left again
    offsetX = paddingX;
  }

  //render the block
  g2.fillRect(offsetX, offsetY, block.getWidth(), block.getHeight());

  offsetX += block.getWidth() + paddingX;
  if( block.getHeight() > currentLargestHeight ) {
    currentLargestHeight = block.getHeight();
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm I understand what you just did ! But the "for each", I need to put a List instead of  `blocks` right ?

Comment: I put some println to check if it still do paintComponent twice, and it still do it, any clue of why ?

Comment: As I said there can be multiple reasons but it shouldn't matter. Many frameworks repaint components multiple times per "frame" (what you'd probably define as a unit of work that would need only one repaint). That's not so uncommon and one more reason why model changes are seperated from the rendering code.

Comment: @A.Arthur that should probably go into a separate question and debugging code for you is way out of scope for SO. Step through your logic with a debugger and have a look at the values you're generating or the dimensions the panel has at the time of painting it (resizing it would cause a repaint).